# Incorrect data showing in VB6 textbox

Tags: vb6

I am setting a datalist which looks like this:
[image]

And I have table like this:

```
+-------------------+  
|---ID----|---NAME--|  
+-------------------+   
|---101---|---CNN---|   
|---102---|---BBM---|  
+-------------------+
```

On the datalist I am using `ID` for `listfield`. I want show the name directly in the textbox when  I choose `ID` list from `listfield`.

e.g. : i choose ID 101 in datalist then show "CNN" in textboxname

```
Private Sub DataList1_Click()
    Txtnama.Text = DataList1.ListField = "nama"
End Sub
```

Problem: the textbox just shows "false".
How do I fix this code.
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line:

`Txtnama.Text = DataList1.ListField = "nama"`

The right hand side of this assignment is the expression

`DataList1.ListField = "nama"`

which is a boolean expression. So the value of the `.Text` property is set to that boolean value.

Probably what you actually want to do is this:

`Txtnama.Text = DataList1.ListField("nama")`

so that you select only the `nama` value from the `DataList` object.

Comment: @Khabibb I haven't run this code, you may have to massage it yourself. The key point is that you are assigning the result of a boolean comparison to your listfield text. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: thanks but my problem have solved with different method today..thanks you